# How to get the current value of the nested for loop and the immediate for loop in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an inventory table that is filled with the ID of the information in our inventory. There are other tables that have the name and ID of those categories. 
I was hoping to use a for loop to fill the currect Inventory data with the IDs according to our inventory.

I was hoping to use a for loop to fill in the data to the InventoryNow table.
I was thinking of doing something like this.

```
For location.location_ID <= EOF
{ 
   For years.years_ID <= EOF
   {
        insert into inventoryNow (wine_ID, years_ID, type_ID,language_ID, Amount)
        values (2,currentvalue(years.years_ID), 1,1,currentvalue(locatio.location_ID,2))
   }
}
```

Is there a function in Access 2010 for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, I'm thinking this may be more suited to an append query if you are planning to do it for all records in the location and years tables. However it can be done in code by looping around with 2 recordsets similarly to what you've described, using something like the following code:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstLoc as DAO.Recordset
Dim rstYears as DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rstLoc = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT location_ID FROM location")
Set rstYears = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT years_ID FROM years")

If rstLoc.RecordCount > 0 And rstYears.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rstLoc.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstLoc.EOF
        rstYears.MoveFirst
        Do Until rstYears.EOF
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO InventoryNow (wine_ID, years_ID, type_ID, language_ID, localtion_ID, Amount) VALUES (2, " & rstYears!years_ID & ", 1, 1, " & rstLoc.location_ID & ", 2)"
            rstYears.MoveNext
        Loop
        rstLoc.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rstLoc.Close
Set rstLoc = Nothing

rstYears.Close
Set rstYears = Nothing

dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL with MS Access and take advantage of a [Cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) to create entries for each year and location:

```
SELECT wines.wine_ID, wines.type_ID, 
    wines.language_ID, wines.Amount, 
    years.years_ID, location.location_id 
INTO AllWines
FROM wines, years, location
```

For example, with 2 wines ( and 2), 2 years (2010 and 2011) and 2 locations ( 1 and 2), you will get

```
wine_ID type_ID language_ID Amount  years_ID    location_id
1       1       1           10      2010        1
2       2       2           20      2010        1
1       1       1           10      2011        1
2       2       2           20      2011        1
1       1       1           10      2010        2
2       2       2           20      2010        2
1       1       1           10      2011        2
2       2       2           20      2011        2
```